# Forms as the rows of a table inside a loop

Tags: javascript, forms, html-table

I have to make a table with all rows either deleting or updating the prices of the products. I have written the following code but it is showing the `tr` tag as an invalid location. Moreover, the form is also not working as required.

```html
<h1>On Manage Products Page by <% out.println(request.getSession().getAttribute("username"));%></h1>
 <div align="center">
  <script>
   function onSubmitForm()
   {
    System.out.println(document.pressed);
    if(document.pressed == 'delete')
    {
     System.out.println("delete");
     document.myForm.action ="deleteProduct.do";
    }
    else
    if(document.pressed == 'update')
    {
     System.out.println("update");
      document.myForm.action ="updateProduct.do";
    }
    return true;
   }
  </script>
  <table>
   <thead><tr><th>PRODUCT NAME<th>PRODUCT PRICE<th> DELETE<th COLSPAN="2"> UPDATE
   
    
    
    <% List products=(List)request.getSession().getAttribute("products"); %>
    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
     <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return onSubmitForm();">
      <input type="hidden" name="productID" value="${product.getProductID()}" />
      <tr>
        
          <td>${product.getProductName()}
          <td>${product.getProductPrice()}
       <td><input type="submit" name="operation" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" value="delete"/>
       <td><input type="text" name="updatedPrice"/>
       <td><input type="submit" name="operation" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" value="update"/>
     </form>
    </c:forEach>
   
    
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Well you have a <th> tag that is not closed. A <tr> that is not closed..... A thead that is not closed.... You than have a form tag as a child of a table element.... Many issues with your generated code.

Comment: closing tags yo! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of issues with your generated code:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr> <-- no closing tag
      <th>PRODUCT NAME  <-- no closing tag
        <th>PRODUCT PRICE <-- no closing tag
          <th> DELETE <-- no closing tag
           <th COLSPAN="2"> UPDATE <-- no closing tag
    <form>  <-- can't be a child of table
      <tr>  <-- not a child of a table/tbody & no closing tag
        <td> <-- no closing tag
        <td> <-- no closing tag
        <td> <-- no closing tag
        <td> <-- no closing tag
        <td> <-- no closing tag
    </form> 
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to close your tags.

In all of your table you are missing closing tags.

e.g. your thead line should rather look like this:

```html
<thead><tr><th>PRODUCT NAME</th><th>PRODUCT PRICE</th><th> DELETE</th><th COLSPAN="2"> UPDATE</th></tr></thead>
```